# Confused about the value

Tags: java

I am going through a JavaCode.I have a question regarding one variable which is being declared and 
used but I am not sure from where it's getting an integer value:

Problem Description:

I have a variable defined inside a class ( named "MyStuffReader") which is as follows:

```
private int CurrModValue;
```

Below in the code, I see the constructor for the class which is defined as follows:

```
 public MyStuffReader(int CurrModValue) 
        {
            this.CurrModValue = CurrModValue;
        }
```

I am wondering does `CurrModValue` generates value by itself?

**My Understanding :**

Thanks guys for your answers. I believe, I figured it out. I have another java file
where I have the following defined:

```
public MyStuffReader[] QR;

private static int x = 10;
```

and then, later down in the code, I have the following defined:

```
QR = new MyStuffReader[x];
```

The code that I originally mentioned above is inside MyStuffReader.java file. so, I believe
the value 10 is getting passed into the constructor.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.CurrModValue` and `CurrModValue` is not the same. `this.CurrModValue` belongs to object while `CurrModValue` is declared only inside method.

Answer (score 2):

No, `CurrModValue` doesn't generate a value by itself.  It's a parameter to your constructor.  If you were to create a `MyStuffReader`, you might code it as:

```
MyStuffReader reader = new MyStuffReader(5);
```

Then `CurrModValue` (the parameter) is `5`, and it gets assigned to `this.CurrModValue`, which also becomes `5`.

Answer (score 0):

The value which is passed as argument in the method will be set to the instance variable `CurrModValue`.

```
public MyStuffReader(int CurrModValue) 
        {
                this.CurrModValue = CurrModValue;
Instance Variable(global)---^            ^----Parameter variable(local)
        }
```